# Time optimization on Vigenère encryption

Tags: python, optimization, encryption, cryptography

I've recently tried to create my own Vigenère encryption script for files. It works without issues with both encryption and decryption mechanisms. But it goes REALLY slow when it comes to "big files". For example, a 772 Ko file took 13.71s and it doesn't look linear as I would expect it to be. supposed it has to do with the fact that I try to read the entire document in a buffer.

the critical part is in only one line, for each byte in the buffer (f.read()) I add the value of the key corresponding. I think this is not optimal but I don't think of another method at the moment.

```
for i, v in enumerate(buf):
            output_buffer += bytes([(v+m*key[i%keylength])%256])
```

"m" is just a parameter that is set to 1 for encryption and -1 for decryption.
The file buffer "buf" and key are bytes, not strings.

If you have any suggestion on how to work with the buffer (not reading and putting into ram the entire document) or with the code for the actual encryption I would be glad to know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can check [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) module and map the file to memory instead `file.read()`

Comment: Also, this `+=` operation seems wasteful, why not just `bytes([(v+m*key[i%keylength])%256 for i, v in enumerate(buf)])` ?

Comment: Wow, just with the simple list by comprehension this took only 0.13s where before it took 13s. Thanks, I didn't notice I could do it here. for mmap though I didn't understand what is different from the basic f.read(). I mean it looks like it has the same methods as fileObject

Comment: With `+=` you're resizing the `output_buffer` every iteration (roughly...) so this is very slow. I haven't used `mmap` yet, but according the documentation you can access the file as an array with `[ ]` without reading it first.

Comment: You can use `& 0xFF` rather than `% 256`. Iterating over all values in pure python could be a bit slow too so if you need something faster, you can probably use Cython or Numpy to make it even faster.